# BalanceOf set pending

Tags: tokens

i am new at the tokens worl, i know that erc20 have some standard parameters and methods, but my question is in a token/smart contract can i had a function that add a pedding Balance to the allowed balance?

What i mean is for exemple Marc has 10 tokens and i send to him 1 token (it will show 11 tokens on his balance) but only after this 2 days Marc is allowed to use 11 token,

Sorry asking this biggers quaestions.

Comment: Ethereum is Turing complete. Therefore, you can indeed add a rule in your smart contract that temporarily blocks a transfer until some cool-down period has passed.

Comment: Thanks @PaulRazvanBerg ! What to you mean with Ethereum is Turing complete?
But just blocking the transfer where this will reflet?
The sender balance? the receiver balance? or none?